# Django: display text between form fields

Tags: django, forms, loops, field

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I am displaying a large form through a loop:

```
    <table>
    {% for field in projectDetailForm %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ field.label_tag }} </td>
        <td> {{ field }} </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

I would like to interrupt the table with the form fields after a few form fields to display more explanations. Since the form is fairly large (20 fields), I would like to avoid the "manual display" of each form field (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727917/display-some-free-text-in-between-django-form-fields)).

**Is there a way to display the text form within the loop, either after the x-th loop or after a specific form field?**

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either use `forloop.counter` or set a custom attribute on a form field on form initialization and display the attribute the same way you display `field.label_tag`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to your form, which will return fields by portions. Something like:

```
def by_5(self):
    iterable = iter(self)
    zipped = zip(*([iterable] * 5)) # replace 5 by desired n
    for z in zipped:
        yield z
    remained = list(iterable)
    if remained:
        yield remained
```

Then in template:

```
<table>
{% for fields in projectDetailForm.by_5 %}
    {% for field in fields %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ field.label_tag }} </td>
        <td> {{ field }} </td>
    </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
    <tr><td colspan="2">Hi there!</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a `{{ forloop.counter }}` and `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` (1-indexed and 0-indexed respectively) that you can use.

For a few more information, check this [Djangobook](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/) link.

Comment: example: `{% ifequal forloop.counter 3 %} <extra stuff> {% endifequal %}`.

Comment: You example will work only for first three fileds, not for every three.

Comment: quoting the question: `either after the x-th loop`

Comment: How would the injection look like if it was supposed to be after a specific field?
`{% ifequal field.label == 'email' %} <add text here> {% endifequal %}`

It does not seem to work.